# How to connect a python flask application to a PCF config service

Tags: python, flask, pymssql, pcf

We have a python flask application, we would like to deploy it to pivotal cloud foundry, I'm looking for a away to use the cloud config service to fetch my database credentials from bitbucket, is this possible?

We have it working for Java Spring applications, but don't know how to do it in Python.